# Adds input to a list of numbers, if the number isn't already in the list - Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am writing a Python program that takes integer numbers from the user and adds them to a list of numbers, if the number isn't already in the list. This normally isn't difficult but I cannot use the in/not in operator, `index()`, or `insert()` functions to accomplish the task.

After I have created the list, I ask the user if they want to replace any values in the list. If they do, then get the value to find and the replacement value.

Once again I can't use the in/not in operator or `index()` function to accomplish the task.

My code:

```
def figure_it_out(numbers_list):
    while True:
        number = int(input("Enter the number for the list: "))
        duplicate = False
        for val in numbers_list:
            if number == val:
                duplicate = True
                break

        if duplicate:
            print("Duplicate found")
        else:
            numbers_list.append(number)
            print("Added {}".format(number))

        answer = input("Would you like to add another number? (y/n): ")
        if answer == 'y':
            continue
        else:
            break

    return numbers_list

def replace_number(current_list):
    while True:
        answer = input("Would you like to replace a number? (y/n): ")

        if answer == 'y':
            count = 0
            num_replace = int(input("What number will you replace: "))
            duplicate = False
            for val in current_list:
                count += 1
                if num_replace == val:
                    duplicate = True
                    break

            if duplicate:
                replacment = int(input("Replace with: "))
                current_list[count - 1] = replacment
                print(current_list)
            else:
                print("There is no number in the list.")    
        else:
            break

    return current_list

def main():
    adding_list = []

    cur_list = figure_it_out(adding_list)

    print(cur_list)

    final_list = replace_number(cur_list)

    print("Your final list is: " + str(final_list))


main()
```

Output:

```
Enter the number for the list: 2
Added 2
Would you like to add another number? (y/n): y
Enter the number for the list: 3
Added 3
Would you like to add another number? (y/n): y
Enter the number for the list: 4
Added 4
Would you like to add another number? (y/n): y
Enter the number for the list: 5
Added 5
Would you like to add another number? (y/n): y
Enter the number for the list: 6
Added 6
Would you like to add another number? (y/n): n
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Would you like to replace a number? (y/n): y
What number will you replace: 5
Replace with: 9
[2, 3, 4, 9, 6]
Would you like to replace a number? (y/n): y
What number will you replace: 6
Replace with: 8
[2, 3, 4, 9, 8]
Would you like to replace a number? (y/n): n
Your final list is: [2, 3, 4, 9, 8]
```

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Try to play through what happens in your for loop when you add the second 3.

Comment: Just do what you mentioned: check the whole list before deciding to add the number or not. You may use a boolean to mark whether the number is  in the list or not and call append (after the whole loop) depends on that boolean.

Comment: Well I have been looking at it and I see that everytime I prompt the user if they want to start again and they say yes, I start the loop through the list at the first element and with the first element being 0 the condition of exists not being equal to what the user input (3) then it will add 3 to the list. So what I need to do is check everything in the list before comparing but I am not sure how to...

Comment: @jack3694078 How would I keep track of that info is my problem?

Comment: You never really use `now` but set it **twice** to `1`. Throw it away and use `while True` instead of `while now == 1`.

Comment: Awesome! I ended up updating the code to try to finish the whole program. I am getting stuck on replacing the value. I wish I could use insert but I can't. I do see how this is helping manipulate the lists but I am not sure why my current solution doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Solved the problem! Solution is now up above. I ended up keeping track of how many times the for loop went through the list to find it's position in order to replace a value. Since I had to start the count variable at 0 I have to [count - 1] when finding the position to replace with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) to take care of removing duplicates:

```
def figure_it_out(adding_list):
    now = 1
    while now == 1:
        added = int(input("Enter the number for the list: "))
        adding_list.append(added) 
        adding_list = list(set(adding_list))

        answer = input("Would you like to add another number? (yes or no): ")

        if answer == 'yes':
            now = 1
        elif answer == 'no':
            return adding_list

def main():
    adding_list = [0]

    cur_list = figure_it_out(adding_list)

    print(cur_list)

main()
```

Comment: Turning a `list` into a `set` to then turn it back into a `list` within the loop is inefficient and not really necessary.

Comment: This is an artificial exercise with imposed restrictions. In this case, my proposed solution is an efficient way of doing it. 
There are clearly much easier was of accomplishing the task, but they tend to require use of the 'banned' operators

Comment: Perhaps you mean your way of doing it is "effective" as in "it works", but I disagree with your assessment of it being "efficient". You could've used a single `set` within the function and then turn it into a `list` just before returning it, but doing that for every iteration is not efficient/required.

Answer (score 0):

I've refactored the code, at the bottom, which produces the following output during its run:

```
Enter the number for the list: 1
Added 1
Would you like to add another number? (y/n): y
Enter the number for the list: 2
Added 2
Would you like to add another number? (y/n): y
Enter the number for the list: 2
Duplicate found
Would you like to add another number? (y/n): n
[1, 2]
```

#### Summary

You basically need to iterate through the list of numbers you have and check each one to see if you can find a duplicate. You only add the new number if a duplicate is not found, which may require iterating over the whole list.

I made some of the following changes:

- Removed your `now` variable: This variable is not really needed and even if it was, it should've been boolean, not an integer;
- Return the output list at the end: The list is returned after we're done with everything outside the loop's body
- Removed the starting non-empty list: There's no need to send in a list that already has numbers in it, so the `[0]` list was replaced by a list that is actually empty

Mainly, it fixes the original issue of adding a number to the list every time the duplication check failed.

#### Refactored Code 1 - Using `list`

This is a minor refactor of your own code, based on the bullet points above.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -B

def figure_it_out(numbers_list):
    while True:
        number = int(input("Enter the number for the list: "))
        duplicate = False
        for val in numbers_list:
            if number == val:
                duplicate = True
                break

        if duplicate:
            print("Duplicate found")
        else:
            numbers_list.append(number)
            print("Added {}".format(number))

        answer = input("Would you like to add another number? (y/n): ")
        if answer == 'y':
            continue
        else:
            break

    return numbers_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(figure_it_out([]))
```

However, I'd prefer using `set`s instead, as shown in the next section.

#### Refactored Code 2 - Using `set` (Recommended)

This would be my recommendation. Using a `set` instead allows you to defer the duplicate-detecting logic to a built-in data structure. It also allows your code to be *simpler*, which is always a good thing.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -B

def figure_it_out(numbers_list):
    numbers_set = set(numbers_list)
    while True:
        try:
            number = int(input("Enter the number for the list: "))
            numbers_set.add(number)
        except ValueError as e:
            print(str(e))

        answer = input("Would you like to add another number? (y/n): ")
        if answer != 'y':
            break

    return list(numbers_set)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(figure_it_out([]))
```

In addition to this, you should use `try`/`except` when getting user input, as shown above. The fact that you ask the user to enter a number does not mean the user will enter a number, which would crash your program with a `ValueError`. Instead, you should *never trust* data that's external to your program (e.g. user input, input files, network packets, etc). They're all attack vectors.

#### Minor Update - Replacing Existing Set Elements

> I am trying to use the same method to replace a value in the list. [...] Do you have any advice for that situation?

To replace an element, just `discard` the existing one and `add` the one you're replacing it with. See my example below:

```
>>> s = set([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> s
{1, 2, 3, 4}
>>> s.discard(2)
>>> s
{1, 3, 4}
>>> s.add(6)
>>> s
{1, 3, 4, 6}
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Mind providing an explanation for the down-vote?

Comment: This seems to work great! Thank you for all the advice, I am trying to use the same method to replace a value in the list. I have updated the code above to show what I have tried and what is happening. Do you have any advice for that situation? Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @mike_tech123: See my updated post, the section on replacing set elements at the bottom. And yes, it does work. I don't think there was a good reason for someone to dvote my post... it works and meets the constraints... :\ but thanks for the up-vote if it was you :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's refactor this a bit.

```
while True:
    new_item = int(input("Enter the number for the list: "))

    for existing_item in adding_list:
        if existing_item == new_item:  # see Note 1
            print("already in there.")
            break
    else:  # see Note 2
        adding_list.append(new_item)
        print("added")

    answer = input("Would you like to add another number? (yes or no): ")
    if answer == 'yes':
        continue  # see Note 3
    elif answer == 'no':
        return adding_list
```

**Notes**

1. In the original code, you append an item to the list after the very first fail of this condition. That's wrong, since we have to make sure that this condition fails for *all* elements in list, not just the first one.
2. This is a `for... else` statement. `else` branch is executed always except for the case when looping was terminated via `break`.
3. No need for special variable to continue looping. Also you might want to introduce a warning if the answer was neither `yes` nor `no`.

**A bit more Pythonic version**

```
while True:
    new_item = int(input("Enter the number for the list: "))
    item_exists = any(item == new_item for item in adding_list)
    if not item_exists:
        adding_list.append(new_item)

    answer = input("Would you like to add another number? (yes or no): ")
    if answer == 'yes':
        continue  # see Note 3
    elif answer == 'no':
        return adding_list
```

Comment: "I cannot use the `in/not in` operator, index(), or insert() functions to accomplish the task."

Comment: @SiHa: I think that means in the context of `if value in valueslist` and similar, not for actually iterating over the collection (e.g. `for i in ints: ....`)

Comment: The code posted here has an undefined variable error, too (i.e. `exists` instead of `existing_item` for loop).

Comment: @ray Thanks for your tip, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set), with the intersection operator standing in for the `in` keyword.

```
def get_numbers():
    numbers = set([])    
    while True:
        new_number = int(input("Enter the number for the list: "))
        if numbers & set([new_number]): # because we're not allowed to use in
            print('already in there')
        else:
            numbers.add(new_number)
            print('added')
        answer = input("Would you like to add another number? (yes or no): ")
        if answer == 'no':
            return list(numbers)
```

But in general a good way to think about this programming challenge might be to focus on how you can replace the parts of the language you're not allowed to use with a new function of your own. You can simply write a function `is_in(element, list_)` and use that wherever you want to use `element in list_`. Any of the following will work.

```
def is_in1(el, L):
    return bool(set(L) & set([el]))

def is_in2(el, L):
    return any(x == el for x in L)

def is_in3(el, L):
    for x in L:
        if x == el:
            return True
    return False

def is_in4(el, L):
    return L.count(el) > 0
```

Comment: There's no need to complicate the code has you have. Just using the `set`'s `add` method would be enough. There's no need to create a 1-element `list` to turn it into a `set` to then check for it's intersection with another `set` to do the duplicate check. Also, doing those conversions within the loop is not really too efficient.

Comment: The OP's code prints a warning to the user if the number is already in the set. To do this without using the `in` operator, we do need to use set intersection or some other workaround. If this is not required then we can drop it and simplify the code. Efficiency is hardly a major consideration in this type of programme.

Comment: There's no indication that printing the message is required. It seems to be more of a debugging aid the OP may've had. I agree with you that efficiency is probably not the main concern, but, as they say in martial arts, "you fight like you train", so if OP learns to write code w/o caring for efficiency, then when efficiency is needed he probably won't do it.

Answer (score 0):

May not be very good solution but this may be done:

```
def figure_it_out(adding_list):
now = 1
while now == 1:
    added = int(input("Enter the number for the list: "))

    adding_list.append(added)

    if adding_list.count(added) == 2:
        print "already there"
        adding_list.remove(added)
        return adding_list
    else:
        answer = input("Would you like to add another number? (yes or no): ")

        if answer == 'yes':
            now = 1
        elif answer == 'no':
            return adding_list
```

Comment: This code can break easily; if the input list already has several repeated entries (e.g. > 2), then your code would allow additional duplicates to be added. There're also issues with using integers as if they were boolean values. In short it repeats some of the issues already highlighted by others and adds a new bug.